# How do we concatenate text along with a PayPal field variable?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, paypal

We are using a standard PayPal Form to collect payments online and have a field for customers to input a pickup date/time, for this we are using the passthrough variable "invoice" per instructions at [PayPal Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) everything worked fine this way until we decided for clarification we would also like to pass along the text "PickUpDate" so its makes sense in the email notifications from PayPal. Instead of just `Invoice ID 2021-08-30T12:30` We would like it to read `Invoice ID PickUpDate:2021-08-30T12:30` We added some JavaScript to get this to work but no success - Any suggestions anyone, hoping for a simple solution somewhere? - Thanks in advance!

**Here is an example of the form as we have it now:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[type="datetime-local"]').change( function() {

$val = 'PickUpDate:' + $(this).val();
$('#invoice').val($val);
    });
});
</script>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin:0;padding:0;" target="PayPal">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@toolcart.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://develop.toolcart.com/?notify=1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Toolcart Sale of: Grey Steel 48x72x24 Cabinet">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase of a Grey Steel 48x72x24 Cabinet">

<div class="text-secondary px-3 form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="date">

  <small>Pickup times 9:00a-6:00p (Mon-Sat)</small>

</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input id="date" type="datetime-local" name="invoice" min="2021-08-26T09:00" class="form-control-sm" id="invoice" required="">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Websale|GrSteel48x72x24Cab|587688|1200.00|Tax|06|72|Total|1272.00">

<div class="text-secondary px-3 form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">
  <small>Please select a payment option:</small>

</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select id="selectbasic" name="amount" class="form-control-sm">
    <option selected="true" value="360">Reservation amount: $360.00</option>
    <option value="1272">Full Price: $1,200.00 + 72.00 Tax</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="paypal@toolcart.com">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://develop.toolcart.com/pickup">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/develop-toolcart-theme/images/paypal.png" class="img-fluid" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

[image]
I would just like to prepend the text of PickUpDate: before the type="datetime-local" values and submit it along with the form if at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used jQuery, try using template literal like this:
I don't know if this will work, just try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[type="datetime-local"]').change( function() {

$val = `PickUpDate: ${$(this).val()}`;
$('#invoice').val($val);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip, that did not work for some reason - any other suggestions?